# What is the substitute of PASSWORD function in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to change the root (default user code) password in MySQL server.
My working environment is Ubuntu, my database version is "Ver 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))"

Most of the posts, suggest the following steps:

1- Stop MySql service; `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`.

2- Run MySql in safe mode with no privilege check : `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

3- Running the update statement below:

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string = PASSWORD('newpassword'),plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where user = 'root';
flush privileges;
```

The "PASSWORD" function is deprecated in the current version therefore the SQL update statement does not throws an error upon execution; I would like to know what is the equivalent function of "PASSWORD" or an alternative procedure to change the password.

Comment: i am guessing you are using mysql 8 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: type "mysql reset root password" into google, and you get lots of useful results, such as https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I was following video tutorials, I actually intend to stick to the instructions given on the Udemy course. The course follows that methodology.